# Any way to find a self-deluded question I answered yesterday?

Tags: discussion

amwhy's suggestion worked, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071388/polynomial-with-small-hessian-determinant

The method was to go back to my profile on Main, choose Activity, then deliberately  choose my Answers; way at the bottom there was a little choice called, in lower case, **recently deleted answers** The new page said **This page shows answers you posted that were deleted in the last 60 days. This includes answers to questions that were deleted.**
and gave a list of links. I think the 60 days refers to the day of deletion. There was one I answered in October where the question was  deleted  in February

I left an answer and a comment, last night I think, at a question I can't find. <strike>I also can't find the user, under the made-up name he used on this site or the (probable) real one he uses on others such as ........</strike>

I had asked for clarification...

If I suspect an OP of possible self-delusion, I "bookmark" the question, so as to be able to see it after deletion. I did not expect trouble this time.

Added: I had misremembered both names for that user; I correctly remembered his  question at ................... [I also found his question from May 2020 that seemed to underlie yesterday's question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654423/polynomials-cannot-be-small-in-a-large-set)

Comment: What was the topic of the question?  Or the relevant tags, if you can remember.  I assume you weren't able to trace via your listed answers, or comments, in your profile?  What was the question from May 2020 that he found, even if the name changed?

Comment: @amWhy it seemed a follow-up to his https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654423/polynomials-cannot-be-small-in-a-large-set   but now about polynomials in two real variables instead of one. As I found that much, I can, at least, leave a comment at the May question asking about this.

Comment: Did you look under your answers to check the "recently deleted answers"  (I'm wondering if, in case the question was deleted, your post might show up there.)

Comment: @amWhy let me see if I can figure out how to do that.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4071388/polynomial-with-small-hessian-determinant

Comment: Click on the "answers" tab in your Activity Tab... scroll to the bottom of the first page: you should see "recently deleted answers."

Comment: Bingo!  Good.  Are you asking if we would undelete the question?  I'd be happy to.

Comment: @amWhy yes, that worked well. I put the link in the question above

Comment: @amWhy I voted to undelete. It is possible that my answer indicated a genuine problem with the conjecture in the question. I would like to know, either way. What seems to happen with Master's level students, or amateurs, is weird conditions nobody has ever heard of before, with question body just "is this weird thing true"

Comment: Indeed, @Will.  I also voted to undelete, but still asked you, nonetheless ;D

Comment: The underlying Question is now **undeleted**.

Comment: "self-deluded question"? "possible self-delusion"? Are we confusing *delude* and *delete*?

Comment: @GerryMyerson well, yes. I threw in ``so as to be able to see it after deletion'' just in case. I guess with auto-correct, people are now fairly tolerant of wrong words, so the replies all fit the intent of my question..... My favorite was http://mathoverflow.net/questions/85610/klein-bottle-exception-to-the-heawood-conjecture/85612#85612

Comment: That's a good one, Will – thanks. Just the other day, someone who wanted to write about "an invertible matrix" got auto-corrected to "an incredible matrix".

Comment: @Gerry  My question, yet unasked, exactly.

Comment: @amWhy it was on purpose. I once asked a question here about cereal downvotes.

Comment: @Will I remember that "cereal downvotes" question you asked! (It had a lot of uptake!) I figured out the dual meaning of "self-deluded question" yesterday, given the search of a recently deleted question.  Very fun!

Comment: Another possibility for the future, would be asking about a "self-dilated question"!

Comment: @amWhy well, it does need to fit the context fairly well. On that note, and somewhat obscured by the closure and community-deletion messages: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805125  I think my answer was deleted by moderators before the question itself.

Comment: That's true, about context.  It looks like answer was deleted by a single user, who I do not recognize as a moderator at that time:  [user642796](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/8348/user642796). But I know one user cannot delete an answer.

Comment: @amWhy what I recall was one comment, apparently regretting the necessity of deleting my answer, saying `Sometimes Will's answers are just so...perfect.' Very nice. Also  fits your idea that more than one deletion vote  was involved

Comment: @WillJagy Indeed, very nice comment.  You do hit the nail on the head far more often, than not, but some users don't always get it.  In any case, keep being you.  You're irreplaceable on math.se!